Chatbot generates answers very late when executing it in the Docker container running in my computer compare to the chatbot execution without docker
I want know 'Why my chatbot generates and types the answer of each question very late than the normal one? I explain you more in detail below:
I have created the chatbot application which has below dependencies:
python 3.10.10
ollama 0.3.6 (https://ollama.com/)
chromadb==0.5.3
streamlit==1.36.0
langchain_core==0.2.9
langchain_community==0.2.5
PyPDF2
pypdf==4.2.0
langdetect==1.0.9

Since my goal is to run the application on the server, I have done the Docker Containerization. For that, I have created the Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and start.sh.

Dockerfile is containing all dependencies installing process, exposing chatbot ports and so on.
docker-compose.yml contains the combination of two services. One for Ollama Container and Second for chatbot application. In Ollama Service, the file start.sh also gets executed.
start.sh contains the name of the Ollama (which starts the Ollama service inside the container), Ollama models and they are going to be pulled which execution of the start.sh file.

At the end, on my local computer, when I execute the command docker-compose up --build, it executes the containerization process, installs Ollama, start the ollama server and pull ollama models inside the docker container. At the end of the process, I open http://localhost:8501 to start the chatbot application. Then I upload the document, write the question and hit enter to get the answer.
About the Answer: I have recieved the answer of a respective question after very long time compare to the scenario where I use the chatbot application on my local computer without the docker container. This is a bit wierd to me.
Why I am receiving answers very late when I execute the answer very late while executing the application on the docker container in compare to the application execution without the docker container.
For your reference, I have added my docker.compose.yml file as below:
services:
  ollama:
    container_name: ollama_v5
    image: ollama/ollama:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - "./ollamadata:/root/.ollama"
      - "./start.sh:/start.sh"  # Mount the script into the container
    ports:
      - "11434:11434"
    entrypoint: /start.sh
    networks:
      - ollama_network

  chatbot:
    container_name: chatbot_v5
    build:
      context: ./    # The directory where Dockerfile and code are located
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - BASE_URL=http://ollama:11434     # Chatbot will access the Ollama API
    ports:
      - "8501:8501"                      
    depends_on:
      - ollama
    networks:
      - ollama_network

networks:
  ollama_network:
    driver: bridge


That seems like a very high-level description of a problem.  Do you know at all what part of the system is being slow, and how it relates to your application code (the source code inside the chatbot container)?  In some environments Docker bind mounts are known to be slow, and one purely speculative guess is that the system is blocked on filesystem I/O to the host ollamadata directory.

@DavidMaze well, I see that it is taking a lot time after hitting the Enter button (after writing the question) to get the answer. So some processing is going in the Ollama container.  For me. it is a bit difficult to know what is this process about.

Do you have any specific options for limit resources?
Something like:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpus: '0.5'       # Limit to 50% of one CPU
      memory: 512M      # Limit to 512 MB of memory

If you want try to set container in privileged mode:
services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    privileged: true  # Enable privileged mode for the container

If this is not helping you maybe have some problems in the docker bridge network

I have added my docker-compose file in my question. Could you please look at it and let me know what is a problem?

Looks good to me - do you need the specific network?Maybe you want to delete all references and try with the default.
If not do the basic tests:
Check if ./ollamadata has the right permissions
Ensure no other containers or services are using the same network name ollama_network (if your case)
Maybe the chatbot itself has some time/wait problems:
depends_on:
- ollama
does NOT guarantee that ollama is fully initialized. (Only that it started after)

I am not quite sure if I need the specific network or not. Should I try removing the ollama_network ?

Unfortunately, there can be many possibilities for your problems. It can be due to the code,network but also to the mount point.
Therefore, I cannot specify my answer. But just like with the privileged (not recommended) but testing can't hurt. Any maybe gives more informations

okay, I will try changing the name of the network and also by removing the network. I will notify you what is the result

so I have just tried chatbot changing the networks name from ollama network to net. But there is no difference in the response time.
But, I get a feeling that there is something to improve in services ollama and how to do this that I do not know.

For most Compose use cases you shouldn't need any networks: blocks at all; Compose will create a network named default and attach all of the containers to it.  Using the default network vs. another name seems unlikely to impact the application performance at all.
